# Are return values going to be passed by rvalue reference in c++0x?

Tags: c++, return-value, c++11, rvalue-reference, return-value-optimization

Let's say I have a function:

```
typedef std::vector<int> VecType;
VecType randomVector();

int processing()
{
    VecType v = randomVector();
    return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
}
```

Does C++0x specifically say the spurious copy will be averted from the return value of randomVector? Or would a compiler need to implement the RVO? It seems to me like  the value `randomVector()` should be treated as an rvalue, and thus v's move constructor should be called, but I'm not completely sure this is true.

Comment: Not a good question, IMHO. The standard can't usefully state what an implementation MAY do, only what it MUST do.

Comment: Actually in the example you had given Return Value Optimization is performed by most compilers... So it is effective without rvalue.

Also rvalue is more important for passing arguments to functions.

Comment: The title of the question is a bit misleading. Your function returns an rvalue and not a reference. But an rvalue reference can bind to it which is what happens in case copy elision can't be performed for some reason and the type has a move-constructor (The move-constructor's parameter is an rvalue reference)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule is the following

- If the compiler can do RVO, then it is allowed to do it, and no copy and no move is made.
- Otherwise, the appropriate constructor is taken.

Like you say, the temporary is an rvalue, and thus the move constructor is selected, because of a rule in `13.3.3.2/3`, which says that a rvalue reference binds to an rvalue better than an lvalue reference. In deciding whether to use the move or the copy constructor, overload resolution will therefor prefer the move constructor.

The rule that the compiler is allowed to perform RVO is written at `12.8/15`.

Answer (score 2):

All return values are considered to be `rvalues` so if the compiler doesn't implement RVO on this case it must use the move constructor rather than the copy constructor.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the "must use the move". AFAIU, assumed a compiler with U/NRVO support, the decision flow is as follows:
1) if RVO-friendly, optimize any move/copy operation,
2) else if move construtor available, use it
3) else if copy constructor available, use it
4) else ill-formed program

Comment: @mloskot I mean the move constructor is selected since it's a better fit for overloading than the copy constructor.

Comment: Got it. The implicit assumption that move ctor exists was unclear to me. As move ctor is selected, but only if it exists.